# Как проверить соответствие введенного числа шаблону?

Tags: регулярные-выражения, bash, shell

Вот шаблон: `grep -vP '(.).*\1'`.

Моя проверка неправильная: `if [ $ps -eq "$grep -vP '(.).*\1'" ]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*POSIX Shell*:

```sh
if echo "$ps" | grep -P -v '(.).*\1' > /dev/null
then
    echo $ps
fi
```

*Bash*:

```bash
if [[ ! $ps =~ (.).*\1 ]]
then
    echo $ps
fi
```

Comment: Благодарю за столь быстрый и подходящий ответ!